Getting RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
On the first render, the prefetched data comes correctly (as shown in the react-query tools)
If I try to refetch/invalidate I get the RangeError message.
So it happens with all the other useFetch I'm using for brevity, I have just mentioned the relevant parts of the code to make it easy to read
I have tried to make the fetchFilters a server action, but it will complain that the response is not of a proper format data
app/api/filters.ts
import type { TFilterData, TFilterDataResponse } from '@/lib/types'

import { baseURL } from './constants'
import { get } from './apiClient'

export const fetchFilters = async (): Promise<TFilterData> => {
  try {
    const path = `${baseURL}/api/dashboard/ratings/filter-options`
    const response = await get<TFilterDataResponse>(path)

    return response?.data?.data ?? {}
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching filters:', error)
    throw error
  }
}

app/lib/hooks/useFilters.ts
'use client'

import { fetchFilters } from '@/app/api/filtersApi'
import { useQuery, keepPreviousData } from '@tanstack/react-query'

export const useFilters = () => {
  const {
    data: filters,
    isLoading: isLoadingFilters,
    error: errorFilters,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['filters'],
    queryFn: fetchFilters,
    placeholderData: keepPreviousData,
  })

  if (errorFilters) {
    console.log(
      '%cGET FILTERS',
      'background: red; color: white; padding: 2px;',
      errorFilters.message
    )
  }

  return {
    filters,
    isLoadingFilters,
    errorFilters,
  }
}

app/dashboard/DashboardClient.tsx
'use client'
  const {
    filters: fullListFilters,
    isLoadingFilters,
    errorFilters,
  } = useFilters()

app/dashboard/page.tsx
'use server'
  const queryClient = new QueryClient()

  await queryClient.prefetchQuery({
    queryKey: ['filters'],
    queryFn: fetchFilters,
  })
  const dehydrateState = dehydrate(queryClient)
  return (
    <HydrationBoundary state={dehydrateState}>
      <DashboardClient />
    </HydrationBoundary>
    )





check the schema model on the server to ensure that you are sending the correct data, including the required fields like id. If the data format is incorrect, the server may not be able to process it properly.
and you can define useMutation for get some correct error : 

I'm not sure why next is firing a POST call to localhost:3000/dashboard, instead of the GET call to fetchFilters as per the above code...

If the server is designed to respond to GET requests, make sure to modify it accordingly if it's currently set to POST.
Verify that both the client-side code and server-side code are aligned in terms of the HTTP method being used.

what does not make sense to me is that the pre-fetch call is fired correctly (GET), and served without errors ( hence the correct data in the RQ tools ).
If I then try to refetch or invalidate the query, it will fire a POST(???).
fetchFilters uses clearly a get method ( otherwise it wouldn't fetch data in the first call )

i suggestion for you test you'r end points with postman , if you have access backend end-points check them agin .
